# Алгоритм распределения точек на площади

Tags: c#, математика, алгоритм

Нужен алгоритм, позволяющий расположить N точек на площади прямоугольника (a, b) максимально равномерно. Прямоугольник в начале координат.
Входные данные: N, a, b.
Выходные данные: массив точек A(x, y)
Максимально равномерно - значит, чтобы вся эта картина смотрелась как равномерная в обывательском отношении.
Я пишу программу на C#, но нужен хотя бы алгоритм. Хотя бы идея.

Comment: Вариант с постоянным шагом?

Comment: А куда, простите, шагать?

Comment: Только вперёд!

Comment: Самый простой вариант - генерить с помощью рандома для оси X целые числа от 0 до a, по оси y от 0 до b. Ну и соответственно таких пар должно быть N.

Comment: Ну то есть «квадратно-гнездовым способом». Или вам надо, чтобы заполнение смотрелось ещё и случайным?

Comment: @wladislaw, "растяните" прямоугольник в линию размером `a * b` точек. 

Тогда, очевидно, что надо разбить ее на N + 1 равный интервал. А потом просто пересчитать координаты точек на этой линии в координаты прямоугольника (для матрицы в номер строки и номер столбца).

Думаю, с этим уже сами справитесь.

Comment: Мне нужно просто раскидать много объектов на ограниченной площади, чтобы они не налезали друг на друга. И чтобы это выглядело более-менее равномерно.

Comment: @avp, в таком случае может получиться, что объекты располагаются близко один над другим, а это не есть то, что нужно.

Comment: @wladislaw, в своем **вопросе** Вы пишете о **точках**.

Comment: @wladislaw, я так думаю, что вам лучше обратиться еще к математикам, поскольку это задача относится к комбинаторной геометрии и они могут подсказать правильные мысли.

Comment: Чтобы решить задачу про объекты, нужно сперва решить таковую про точки.

Comment: @wladislaw, если нужно что-то реальное, то попробуйте поискать программы "размещения и трассировки" (если не изменяет память, их именно так называли) для ECAD (САПР электроники).

Конечно, решения равномерного размещения прямоугольников там Вы вряд ли найдете, но перебор размещений с целью оптимизации, скажем, температуры -- наверняка есть.

Comment: Сюда же задача экономного раскроя листовых материалов

Comment: @Alex Krass: Прежде надо как следует сформулировать критерий *равномерности.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Речь идет о площади, решать стоит через площадь, чтобы точки не выстроились в столбцы или диагонали, т.е. они должны быть равномерно распределены как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали.

```
S=a*b;      // площадь прямоугольника
Sp=S/N;     // площадь на одну точку
x=sqrt(Sp); // длина стороны квадрата, в котором сидит одна точка (например, в центре)
```

Таким образом, линия - это полоса шириной x. Только проблемы будут с краями, видимо. И заполнение получится сеткой, если не вводить специальные смещения в четных/нечетных строках или еще как нибудь.

Эта задача напоминает триангуляцию или разбиение плоскости на другие регулярные структуры.

**UPD:**

Теперь можно "подогнать" квадратики x * x под пропорции прямоугольника a * b.

```
h=ceil(b/x);  // высота ячейки
w=Sp/h;      // ширина ячейки
```

Далее заполняем построчно с "переносом" части ячейки на следующую строку, т.к. ширина прямоугольника a в общем случае не кратна ширине ячейки w.

**UPD2:**

Можно посмотреть [планигоны](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_mathematics/3977/%D0%9F%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%9D), [паркеты](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82_%28%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) и [разбиение (триангуляцию) Делоне](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%F0%E8%E0%ED%E3%F3%EB%FF%F6%E8%FF_%C4%E5%EB%EE%ED%E5). Видимо, "квадратно-гнездовой способ" [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) и идея в этом ответе примерно из той области, это все к математикам.

Comment: Думал об аналогичном решении, только с применением в дополнение к описанному вычисления отношения сторон прямоугольника, как-то так: dx = a/b, dy = b/a, x = sqrt(Sp)*dx, y = sqrt(Sp)*dy. Правда затормозил на том, что заполнение происходит сеткой и вроде получается не совсем то, что надо.

Comment: Я тоже подумал над тем, как "равномеризовать", предложение (чистая эвристика) добавлю в ответ.

Comment: Не влезая в какие-то математические дреби, это, пожалуй, самый хороший вариант. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
количество точек в строке = N / a*b
```

Comment: а если N не делится на a/b?

Comment: a | b == 0?

Comment: Мое гадание по кофе подсказывает, что имелся ввиду такой вариант: 1/(5*5) = 0.04 точки в строке. Что довольно странно.

Comment: Вот и мне так кажется.